# sscanf read 1 instead 3 float

Tags: c++, scanf

i have lib with function for loading obj mesh...
part of this function

```
    case 'v':
        if(string[1] == ' ')
        {
            have_verticles = true;
            tmp_Vertex.set(0,0,0);
            sscanf(&string[2],"%f %f %f",&tmp_Vertex.x,&tmp_Vertex.y,&tmp_Vertex.z);
            Verticles.push_back(tmp_Vertex);
        }
        else if(string[1] == 't')
        {
            have_texcoords = true;
            tmp_Texcoord.set(0,0);
            sscanf(&string[2],"%f %f",&tmp_Texcoord.x,&tmp_Texcoord.y);
            TexCoords.push_back(tmp_Texcoord);
        }
        else if(string[1] == 'n')
        {
            have_normals = true;
            tmp_Normal.set(0,0,0);
            sscanf(&string[2],"%f %f %f",&tmp_Normal.x,&tmp_Normal.y,&tmp_Normal.z);
            Normals.push_back(tmp_Normal);
        }
        break;
```

if i compile lib with main.cpp as executable, all works fine
but if i compile lib as DLL and try to execute this func from another app,
sscanf ingore last 2 float and reads only first...
How fix this ?

Sorry my horrible english..

upd:

example file (part)

```
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
```

sscanf reads only first floats...

upd2:
string is a

```
char string[256];
```

after sscanf() with input string

```
"1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000"   
tmp_Vertex.x = 1.0 tmp_Vertex.y = 0.0 tmp_Vertex.z = 0.0
```

sscanf() return 1..

Full function code...

```
renderer::IMesh* CMeshOBJImporter::LoadOBJ(io::IFile* file)
{
    bool have_verticles = false;
    bool have_texcoords = false;
    bool have_normals   = false;

    std::vector<core::vector3f> Verticles;
    std::vector<core::vector2f> TexCoords;
    std::vector<core::vector3f> Normals;
    std::vector<core::vector3s> Indices;

    core::vector3f tmp_Vertex;
    core::vector2f tmp_Texcoord;
    core::vector3f tmp_Normal;
    core::vector3s tmp_Index;

    char string[256];
    while(read_string(file,string) != 0)
    {
        switch(string[0])
        {
        case '#':
            continue;
        case 'o':
            continue;
        case 'm':
            continue;
        case 'u':
            continue;
        case 'v':
            if(string[1] == ' ')
            {
                have_verticles = true;
                tmp_Vertex.set(0,0,0);
                sscanf(string + 2,"%f %f %f",&tmp_Vertex.x,&tmp_Vertex.y,&tmp_Vertex.z);
                Verticles.push_back(tmp_Vertex);
            }
            else if(string[1] == 't')
            {
                have_texcoords = true;
                tmp_Texcoord.set(0,0);
                sscanf(&string[2],"%f %f",&tmp_Texcoord.x,&tmp_Texcoord.y);
                TexCoords.push_back(tmp_Texcoord);
            }
            else if(string[1] == 'n')
            {
                have_normals = true;
                tmp_Normal.set(0,0,0);
                sscanf(&string[2],"%f %f %f",&tmp_Normal.x,&tmp_Normal.y,&tmp_Normal.z);
                Normals.push_back(tmp_Normal);
            }
            break;
        case 'f':
            std::vector<core::vector3s> Face;

            char* tok = strtok(&string[1]," \n");
            while(tok != NULL)
            {
                tmp_Index.set(0,0,0);

                if(have_verticles && !have_texcoords && !have_normals)
                    sscanf(tok,"%d",&tmp_Index.x);
                else if(have_verticles && have_texcoords && !have_normals)
                    sscanf(tok,"%d/%d",&tmp_Index.x,&tmp_Index.y);
                else if(have_verticles && !have_texcoords && have_normals)
                    sscanf(tok,"%d//%d",&tmp_Index.x,&tmp_Index.z);
                else if(have_verticles && have_texcoords && have_normals)
                    sscanf(tok,"%d/%d/%d",&tmp_Index.x,&tmp_Index.y,&tmp_Index.z);

                tmp_Index.add(-1);
                Face.push_back(tmp_Index);
                tok = strtok(NULL," \n");
            }
                //Triangulate face
                if(Face.size() > 3)
                {
                    //!< If Face = Quad we use predefined vertex positions (it's faster)
                    //!< Else we split big polygon(more than 4 vertex) on triangles

                    if(Face.size() == 4)
                    {
                        Face.push_back(0);
                        Face.push_back(0);
                        Face[4] = Face[3];
                        Face[3] = Face[2];
                        Face[5] = Face[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::vector<core::vector3s> TriangulatedFaces;
                        u32 FaceSize = Face.size()-2;
                        for(u32 i = 0; i < FaceSize; i++)
                        {
                            TriangulatedFaces.push_back(Face[0  ]);
                            TriangulatedFaces.push_back(Face[1+i]);
                            TriangulatedFaces.push_back(Face[2+i]);
                        }
                        Face.clear();
                        Face.insert(Face.end(),TriangulatedFaces.begin(),TriangulatedFaces.end());
                    }
                }
                Indices.insert(Indices.end(),Face.begin(),Face.end());
                break;
            }
        }

        renderer::CVertexArray* VertexArray = new renderer::CVertexArray();

        u32 IndicesSize = Indices.size();
        for(u32 i = 0; i < IndicesSize; i++)
        {
            renderer::SVertex Vertex;

            if(have_verticles)
                Vertex.Position = Verticles[Indices[i].x];
            if(have_texcoords)
                Vertex.TexCoord = TexCoords[Indices[i].y];
            if(have_normals)
                Vertex.Normal   =   Normals[Indices[i].z];

            VertexArray->addVertex(Vertex);
        }

        u32 VertexFormat = renderer::EVF_VERTEX;
        if(have_texcoords)
            VertexFormat |= renderer::EVF_TEXCOORD;
        if(have_normals)
            VertexFormat |= renderer::EVF_NORMAL;


        VertexArray->setPrimitiveType(renderer::EPT_TRIANGLES);
        VertexArray->setVertexFormat(VertexFormat);

        renderer::IMesh* newMesh = new renderer::CMesh(VertexArray,NULL);
        VertexArray->release();

        return newMesh;
    }
```

Comment: what do your strings look like?

Comment: 1) Proper usage of scanf() requires the correct argument string as well as the correct argument types. You didn't state what type is tmp_Normal.x, tmp_Normal.y, etc. are. Please post this information. 2) We don't know what string[] is. Please post that definition, as we do not know if string is an array, vector, a custom class with an operator [], etc...

Comment: For C++, why not use [string stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)?

Comment: Ok, i found solution...
Before all i call setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian"); after this ALL scanf functions work incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `&string[2]` to `string + 2`.
The first parameter to sscanf should be a `char*` (C-string).

Comment: No, sscanf still read only first float...
p.s. type of &string[2] = string+2 = float .. or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you only read data from a character.
try this following code:

```
sscanf(string.c_str(),"%f %f %f",&tmp_Vertex.x,&tmp_Vertex.y,&tmp_Vertex.z);
```

c_str() : Get C string equivalent

Comment: Ops... i dont write before.. string is a char string[256];

Comment: just remove .c_str() :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a suggestion, too long to put in comment:

Define these functions (note `to_string` is c++11)

```
using std::string;
using std::to_string;

void sscanf_2( const char* str, const char* fmt, float *f1, float *f2 ) {
    size_t n = sscanf(str,fmt, f1, f2 );
    if (n != 2) throw std::runtime_error("sscanf_2: bad parse, str="+string(str)+" fmt="+string(fmt)+" n="+to_string(n));
}

void sscanf_3( const char* str, const char* fmt, float *f1, float *f2, float *f3 ) {
    size_t n = sscanf(str,fmt, f1, f2, f3 );
    if (n != 3) throw std::runtime_error("sscanf_3: bad parse, str="+string(str)+" fmt="+string(fmt)+" n="+to_string(n));
}
```

Use those functions as appropriate in your code, replacing `sscanf` with either `sscanf_2` or `sscanf_3`.  If sscanf cannot parse the required number of fields it will throw an exception, which you can catch in your program as appropriate.  This might help you figure out what's wrong.